# Sitecore 9 in Azure PaaS : Add Application Insights SDK

Tags: azure, sitecore-api, paas

For Sitecore 9 on Azure PaaS and newer versions, what is the best practice to Add and configure the Application Insights SDK in Visual Studio to generate some telemetry in Visual Studio.
As we are using Helix principle and I want to check my site dependencies and add system diagnostics on run time from the Application Insight/Application map

I have configured the application insight SDK using Microsoft Azure link 
 but the map doesn't include any dependencies 
:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default Paas installation packages will have Application insights enabled by default, so you should not have to configure anything further in Visual Studio for them to send telemetry to App Insights.

However, by default Sitecore 9 does not collect the dependency telemetry, and hence the Application map is unavailable.  This is to "optimize resource consumption" as outlined in the kb link below.

However, you can enable the dependency telemetry by modifying ApplicationInsights.config in your solution. Details from the following KB article:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/201177

> To enable the collection of "dependency" telemetry events, uncomment the following line in the ApplicationInsights.config file located inside the website root folder:

```
<!-- <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/> -->
```

Keep in mind that on a busy site this will collect a lot of data, so keep an eye on your App Insights service quotas.  You can set caps and warnings in Azure portal if neccessary.  Additionally you may see a performance hit enabling the dependency telemetry (as alluded to in the KB), so test and provision appropriately to make sure you're not introducing too much overhead.

Comment: Thank you @George Tucker for your help

I need this to monitor my site and to utilize our environment in Azure because we keep receiving Time out exception in Sitecore Content Management application Service.

Should I wait for sometime to receive any data in the application map after uncomment that line because I am receiving "No Data Available"

Comment: You can check if data is flowing by having a look at the "Live Stream" blade in app insights. That will indicate if your configuration is correct.  If you're looking for insights into a timeout, I suggest checking the application logs (in app insights as trace items) via the search blade.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have removed the application insight SDK and enabled the line you sent above, now I am able to see the site dependencies.